# Elasticsearch decay parameters

Tags: elasticsearch, scoring

I have three groups of docs (e.g. docs from registered, verified and unregistered users), and I want to score them using decay function.

However, I need to have different speed of decay (scale) for each of this three groups of documents, so that docs from verified users were around the top longer than docs from unregistered users.

It seems, it is not possible to use doc field as a parameter for a decay function. Maybe, there is some other way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be done with **function_score**, "filter" of function definition:

```
{
  "size": 100,
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "score_mode": "multiply",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "status": 0
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "categories": 29
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "user_type": 1
            }
          },
          "weight": 1,
          "gauss": {
            "date_created": {
              "scale": "7d",
              "decay": 0.9
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "filter": {
            "not": {
              "term": {
                "user_type": 1
              }
            }
          },
          "weight": 0.8,
          "gauss": {
            "date_created": {
              "scale": "7d",
              "decay": 0.8
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```